# SVG animateTransform not working on FF and IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox, animatetransform

I have created a custom *PreLoader* screen using <kbd>[**animateTransform**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform)</kbd> and <kbd>[**keyframes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)</kbd> on my svg image.

When I was working on the images they are working perfectly fine on all the browsers. But as soon as I've used them in my *PreLoader* they start working abruptly.

As you can check their behavior in Snippet below, it will work perfectly in **Chrome** but on **Firefox** and **IE** they are even visible at all.

### Code Snippet

```js
//PreloadMe
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
  $('.la-anim-9').addClass('la-animate'); //to run the preloader lines animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.preloader-logo img')
      .fadeOut(400, function() {
        $('.preloader-logo img').attr('src', 'http://gdurl.com/wzWh');
        //to create the red logo effect
      }).fadeIn(400);
  }, 4500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
  }, 6000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css({
      'overflow': 'visible'
    });
    //to revert back the normal scrolling
  }, 6100);
});
```

```css
/* Preloader */

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
  z-index: 99;
  /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
.la-anim-9 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
}
.preloader-logo {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 366px;
  height: 133px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.preloader-logo img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate .preloader-logo {
  opacity: 1;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline {
  position: fixed;
  background: #373737;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-top,
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-left,
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-right {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-bottom {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.la-anim-9 .preloadline-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate .preloadline-right {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: height 1.35s linear 0.3s;
  transition: height 1.35s linear 0.3s;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate .preloadline-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.35s linear 1.65s;
  transition: width 1.35s linear 1.65s;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate .preloadline-left {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: height 1.35s linear 3s;
  transition: height 1.35s linear 3s;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate .preloadline-top {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.35s linear 4.35s;
  transition: width 1.35s linear 4.35s;
}
.la-anim-9.la-animate {
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 5.7s;
  transition: border 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 5.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="la-anim-9">
    <div class="preloadline preloadline-top"></div>
    <div class="preloadline preloadline-right"></div>
    <div class="preloader-logo">
      <img src="http://gdurl.com/5HVo" alt="Alt Text" />
    </div>
    <div class="preloadline preloadline-bottom"></div>
    <div class="preloadline preloadline-left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried almost everything and digging up the *SO* as well *Google* for this but haven't found and decent solution that will work for both **Firefox** and **IE**.

Comment: For FF, it seems it is because of the CSS animation. Probably related : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190881, which is marked as "Fixed"... A workaround would be to use an `<object>` element. For IE, it doesn't support SMIL animations, so you would have to use some javascript fallback like [FakeSmile](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile) library, which won't work in an `<img>` tag, so here again , you'd have to use an `<object>` or `<iframe>` element.

Comment: @Kaiido, I've gone through the same but it didn't help and I dont know how they marked it solved may be their case would be different from mine. If I have to use object then it will be real pain for me as I have spent hours to make this animation work, and as far as for `iframe`, I dont think it will be a wiser decision to use it on *PreLoader* Screen.

Comment: well CSS wise, object and img are really similar, you just have to change your markup to `<object data="http://gdurl.com/5HVo"></object>`, you'll just loose the alt, but this can be workedaround with an `onerror="this.data = 'data:text/plain, your alt text';"`

Comment: @Kaiido thanks a ton mate! I really appreciate your help, that *`object`* tag has done the trick, working fine on *Firefox*  now, and in case of *IE* I will do a workaround to manage the *PreLoader*.

Comment: Well for IE, you just have to include a `<script>` tag pointing to the library I gave you (fakeSmile) inside your svg document.

Comment: @Kaiido I just used [**FakeSmile**](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile), and yes Its really amazing now my animation is working on both IE as well as FF. You should post it as an answer. thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems you are facing are not the same.

**For Firefox**, this seems to be a resurgence of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190881) which has been marked as "Resolved". When I tried your file without the CSS declaration, I could see it inside an `<img>` tag.
I didn't dig really deep in your markup to see if something else is causing it though.

The workaround here is to use an other element than `<img>` : `<object>`, `<iframe>` or `<embed>` should do.

**For IE**, it's simply that this browser doesn't support SMIL animations. You'll then have to use a javascript fallback library (such as [FakeSmile](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile)), and include it inside your SVG document.
But here again, you'll have to leave `<img>` tag, since we can't execute scripts form this element. Any of the 3 above will do too.

So this would make you change your HTML markup to

```
<div class="preloader-logo">
  <object data="http://gdurl.com/5HVo"></object>
</div>
```

and add one

```
<script xlink:href="pathTo/FakeSmile.js"></script>
```

inside your svg document, and you'll get support back for both IE and FF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your support. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm still struggling about this bug in FF though. I hope I'll have some time to dig into it.